# property not initialized at super.init

Tags: ios, swift

I have a simple swift class:

```
class School: NSObject {
    var myData: NSData
    var timestamp: NSDate
    var id: Int

    override init() {
        //ERROR: Property 'self.myData' not initialized at super.init call
        super.init()
    }
}
```

Why I get the compiler error mentioned above?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

All properties must be initialized before you chain up to a super initializer. Otherwise you would end up with uninitialized memory, which is not allowed in Swift. Therefore, you must set `myData`, `timestamp`, and `id` or make them optional.

Comment: question: super.init() should be use when you inherit from another class right, where that super init called the init function from the superclass?